# Change DIV background image on .hover - with fade

Tags: image, background, hover, fade

I'm looking to fade from one background image to another using a standard .hover link.

An example of the link without the fade can be seen here:
http://www.makestudio.co.uk/sites/seven/

Other pages within the site will use similar layout only different background images for the links. Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

Don't need jquery, just css

```
<div id="thisdiv">Content</div>
```

CSS...

```
#thisdiv { height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: #600;
transition: 2s;
-moz-transition: 2s;
-webkit-transition: 2s; }
#thisdiv:hover {
background-color: #006;
transition: 2s;
-moz-transition: 2s;
-webkit-transition: 2s;}
```

[jsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/AK6L7/)

With an image you can use CSS for opacity to fade the image then brighten it up on hover. You can't really fade between images without jquery though.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of the transition property - stubbornness keeps me looking for that image alternative. I believe I've found a working possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really fade images with CSS.

If you want to try something, though, you can use `-webkit-animate` and other browser-specific prefixes to animate the opacity of the element itself. You'll need to tinker with it.

Google **CSS3 animations** for more information. You want to animate the `opacity` property.

Answer (score 0):

Hover on any element won't work on old browsers, so you need to be sure your client base either doesn't use old browsers, or you degrade gracefully.

I'd suggest using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com). Its a js library that will help you have cool effects for up to date browsers while degrading well for ones that don't support your particular feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS transitions to change opacity of the image and reveal another image underneath it.

[Demo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9973028/WEB/backgroundimage.html)

Answer (score 0):

you may use jQuery to just fade in.
Otherwise, if u insist CSS, you may find this some what helpful.

[Try this JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gU4sw/7/)

```
<!-- HTML-->
<div id="id1" class="item"><a href="#">DIV1</a></div> 
<div id="id2" class="item"><a href="#">DIV2</a></div> 
<div id="id3" class="item"><a href="#">DIV3</a></div> 
<div id="rightDiv">
<a id="id1match" class="region"> </a>
<a id="id2match" class="region"> </a>
<a id="id3match" class="region"> </a>

<div id="fakeDiv1" class="fake"><a href="#">DIV1</a></div>
<div id="fakeDiv2" class="fake"><a href="#">DIV2</a></div>
<div id="fakeDiv3" class="fake"><a href="#">DIV3</a></div>
</div>

<!--CSS -->
/* style of left side */
```