# backgroundColor does not animate, but width does in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want the color of my div.navBtn elements to change through an animation effect. It isn't working out and I don't know why.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("button").click(function()
  {
    $("div.navBtn").animate(
    {
      width:'+=10px',
      backgroundColor: "#aa0000"
    });
  });
});
```

`backgroundColor` is what does the actual color changing but it does not work. Width `+=10` works perfectly, backgroundColor does absolutely nothing. Is the syntax wrong or something??? I copied `"backgroundColor: "#aa0000""` from another help posting here. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090023/jquery-animate-fade-background-color-or-image-in-div-when-hover-a-link

Answer (score 1):

You have to include jQuery UI in order to animate colours with jQuery.animate.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot animate colour's with `jQuery` You may have to use CSS instead or `jQuery UI`, but you shouldn't include that just to animate colours.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090023/jquery-animate-fade-background-color-or-image-in-div-when-hover-a-link

Comment: Yes what about it? Please don't tell me your saying **There's a PLUGIN for that**